# GCC -pipe Will Cause Errors

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, g++, gnu-assembler

The gcc -pipe switch can speed up compilation. However, in gcc 13.2.0, that causes a problem. If I use -pipe to compile some files, especially slightly large files(sometimes even hello,world can cause problems), then gcc will give me several errors like:
`[Standard input] Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is '.'`
To clarify, I provide a sample on [GitHub](https://Github.com/zxunge/gccpipetest). Those Errors often occurs when Building with wxWidgets, morw info can be found There.

In gcc 13.1.0, -pipe doesn't cause those Errors. It'll be all right if I disable -pipe switch. I think that might be a bug in gcc 13.2.0, any ideas?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: On what OS, for what architecture?  Are you using anything like ccache?  Also please include a [mcve] of source code that reproduces this.

Comment: Question edited, Maybe it can help.